# How to handle multiple endpoints in ASP.Net Core 3 Web API properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I have 2 methods to handle HTTP GET requests, first one for `int` type input and the other one for `string` type input.

```
//GET : api/Fighters/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Fighter>> GetFighter(int id) 
{
    var fighter = await _context.Fighters.FindAsync(id);

    if (fighter == null) 
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return fighter;
}

// GET: api/Fighters/Alex
[Route("api/Fighters/{name}")]
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Fighter>>> GetFighter (string name) 
{
    return await _context.Fighters.Where(f => f.Name == name).ToListAsync();
}
```

when i send HTTP GET this exception appears (in Postman):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

FighterGameService.Controllers.FightersController.GetFighter (FighterGameService)
FighterGameService.Controllers.FightersController.GetFighter (FighterGameService)
FighterGameService.Controllers.FightersController.GetFighter (FighterGameService)
FighterGameService.Controllers.FightersController.GetFighter (FighterGameService)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

`GET api/fighters/1` would cause error obviously since "`1`" could be either `int` or `string` so i solved my problem by combining two methods:

```
// GET: api/Fighters/5
// GET: api/Fighters/Alex
[HttpGet("{idOrName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Fighter>>> GetFighter(string idOrName)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(idOrName, out int id))
    {
        return await _context.Fighters.Where(f => f.Id == id).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await _context.Fighters.Where(f => f.Name == idOrName).ToListAsync();
    }

}
```

this works however this doesn't feel right at all. What is the proper way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-constraint-reference)

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Fighter>> GetFighter(int id) 

[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Fighter>>> GetFighter (string name)
```

Comment: Why cant you just type {name:alpha}? It throws 404 HttpError when doing that

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem in Core 3.0.  I finally found the solution was to put a route attribute on the action - e.g. `[Route("NodeInfo")]`. That fixed it

Comment: This is the correct answer at least when you have an endpoint with the same signature

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the solution for .Net Core 3.1 or higher Version:Use [Route("RouteName")]

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateUserRole")]
       // [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserRole([FromBody] AssignUserRole assignUserRole)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInfo("Attempted submission attempted");

                if (assignUserRole == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarn("Empty request submitted");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarn("User data was incomplete");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                var User = _Mapper.Map<Users>(assignUserRole);
                _UserRoleRepository.AssignRoleUser(assignUserRole);
                _logger.LogInfo("User Role created");
                Audit_logs audit = new Audit_logs()
                {
                    uid = User.id,
                    action = "Create User Role",
                    log = $"{assignUserRole.rolename} Role has created",
                    datetime = DateTime.Now
                };
                await _audit_Logs.Create(audit);
                return Created("Create User Role", new { assignUserRole });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalError($"{ex.Message}-{ex.InnerException}");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer, as it lacks explanation, context and the code is not relative the OP's original code.