# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.Net Core WebAPI, I got below requirement as

I have 2 methods to handle HTTP GET requests, the first one for GetCustomer by id(`string`) and the other one to GetCustomer by email(`string`).

```
//GET : api/customers/2913a1ad-d990-412a-8e30-dbe464c2a85e
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer([FromRoute]string id) 
{
   
}

// GET: api/customers/myemail@gmail.com
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomerByEmail([FromRoute]string email) 
{
   
}
```

when I try to this Endpoint, I get exception as:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
```

Which is quite Obivious & understood.

It could be easily addressed by appending/prepending some string in the route like

```
/api/customer/{id}

/api/customer/emai/{id}
```

However not so convinced with this apporach however on googling I get the below SO link

- [How to handle multiple endpoints in ASP.Net Core 3 Web API properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157040/how-to-handle-multiple-endpoints-in-asp-net-core-3-web-api-properly)

But this guy has one parameter as int while the other as string so route constraint rescued.

however, I see some people posting/suggesting on the same post to add `[Route("")]` but I didn't get how this attribute is useful ?

afaik, `Route("")` and `HTTPGet("")` //any HttpVerb serves the same purpose?

Anyways how could I handle my requirement elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference) to disambiguate between the two routes:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id:guid}")]

[HttpGet("{name}")]
```

You could also create your own `email` constraint or use `regex(.)` constraint for the email parameter.

Comment: what if id is regular string

Comment: Then maybe you can add an `email` constraint to the second one? If not, the two *cannot* be disambiguated - how would ASP.NET Core know which route to call if both could be *any string*?